# Numbering for a theorem and enumerated list within that theorem

Tags: numbering, lists, theorems, amsthm, roman-numerals

I have the following `amsthm` environment defined

```
\newtheorem{cslist}{Comparative Static Hypothesis}
```

In instances of `cslist`, I would like to have an enumerated list like this.

```
 \begin{cslist}{Response A}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item \label{item:pps1} Pred 1
 \item \label{item:pps2} Pred 2
 \end{enumerate}  
 \end{cslist}
```

Currently, this renders as `Comparative Static Hypothesis 1`, with points `1` and `2`. I want to have the hypothesis numbering be `CS#`. Thus, my hypothesis would be `Comparative Static Hypothesis CS1`. Then, the points in the enumerate should be `CS1.i` and `CS1.ii`.

How do I go about making this happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could redefine the numbering of your "Comparative Static Hypothesis" to show `CS#` using

```
\renewcommand{\thecslist}{CS\arabic{cslist}}
```

and then use the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to format the labels printed within your `cslist` environment using `label=\thecslist.\roman*` (here `\roman*` will print lower case Roman numerals). Since the labels are now "bigger" than the regular ones, adding `leftmargin=*` will allow for proper alignment with the left margin.

Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\newtheorem{cslist}{Comparative Static Hypothesis}
\renewcommand{\thecslist}{CS\arabic{cslist}}%
\begin{document}

\begin{cslist}{Response A}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\thecslist.\roman*,leftmargin=*]
    \item \label{item:pps1} Pred 1
    \item \label{item:pps2} Pred 2
  \end{enumerate}  
\end{cslist}

For more information, see~\ref{item:pps1} and~\ref{item:pps2}.

\end{document}​
```

If this usage is more prevalent, perhaps defining a new list `cslistenum` (say) with default options `label=\thecslist.\roman*,leftmargin=*` could be defined using

```
\newlist{cslistenum}{enumerate}
\setlist{cslistenum}[label=\thecslist.\roman*,leftmargin=*]
```

Alternatively, the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) could also be used to reformat `enumerate` with these options by default using `\AtBeginEnvironment`, thereby automating the reformatting. It all depends on the usage.

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. So, for any theorem environment xyz, then \thexyz is the command that makes the name, and xyz is a counter, and \arabic formats the counter? That's really cool. Thank you!

Comment: @stevejb: Yes, for a theorem environment `xyz`, an accompanying counter `xyz` is defined. `\thexyz` prints the counter in whichever way it has been set to print: `\arabic{xyz}` prints "regular" numerals; `\alph{xyz}` [`\Alph{xyz}`] prints lower [upper] case letters, and `\roman{xyz}` [`\Roman{xyz}`] prints lower [upper] case Roman numbers. `\value{xyz}` is (La)TeX's internal representation of the counter `xyz`, and could be completely different from what `\thexyz` prints.